# how to parallelize this for-loop using reduction?

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

I am trying to make this for-loop parallelized by using Openmp, i recognized that there reduction in this loop so i added "#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+,ftab)",but it did not work and it gave me this error :
error: user defined reduction not found for ‘ftab’.

```
   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:ftab)
    for (i = 1; i <= 65536; i++) ftab[i] += ftab[i-1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you want to do is [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). It can be done in parallel. A simple way is to use [thrust::inclusive_scan](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__prefixsums.html) with OpenMP or TBB backend.

```
thrust::inclusive_scan(thrust::omp::par, ftab, ftab + 65536, fab);
```

or

```
thrust::inclusive_scan(thrust::tbb::par, ftab, ftab + 65536, fab);
```

You could also implement it by yourself as referenced in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum).